# EF Identity in WebAPI 2 stops working when model changed

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, identity

I want to build a website in Angular with a web service that Android/iOS can use.  I finally found a great tutorial that helped me set that up.  The next step, is to extend the Identity Model.  So, I added a property.  Then I started to get an exception:

"The model backing the 'AuthContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

So, when I follow those instructions, I get this:

```
 Enable-Migrations
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.
Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
At C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:62
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom <<<< ((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781 char:50
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CreateInstance:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.P
owerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
At C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809 char:31
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName AngularJSAuthentication.API.AuthContext
The project 'AngularJSAuthentication.API' failed to build.
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName AngularJSAuthentication.API.AuthContext
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.
Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
At C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:62
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom <<<< ((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781 char:50
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CreateInstance:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.P
owerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
At C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809 char:31
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

PM> Enable-Migrations
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.
Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
At C:\copa\AngularJSAuthentication-master\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:62
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom <<<< ((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I've changed my initialiser in Startup ( commented shows what it was )

```
Database.SetInitializer<AuthContext>(null);// <AuthContext>());//, AngularJSAuthentication.API.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

and in a static constructor in the context class ( this combination is what i did in another project )

```
static AuthContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AuthContext>(new AuthContextInitialiser());
    }
```

I am at a loss, I've googled, but the solutions I see, don't seem to work.  VS is running as admin.  I just want EF to not care about my DB, and to trust me that it's the way it should be....

Actually, if I tell it to replace my DB ( which I don't like ), I get this error:

```
Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration
```

There is no path that just leaves me alone and trusts me to manage my own DB...

Thanks

Comment: CAn someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ? No-one ever answers me....

Answer (score 0):

This exception and HResult code comes if there's a security restriction preventing the assemblies to be loaded.
Typical causes:

- Network share or drive: copy file to hard drive
- DLL copied from other machine: right-click and unblock it